# Contain in a list the values that appear in an array in a given percentage

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array called "data" which contains the following information.

```
[['amazon',
  'phone',
  'serious',
  'mind',
  'blown',
  'serious',
  'enjoy',
  'use',
  'applic',
  'full',
  'blown',
  'websit',
  'allow',
  'quick',
  'track',
  'packag',
  'descript',
  'say'],
 ['would',
  'say',
  'app',
  'real',
  'thing',
  'show',
  'ghost',
  'said',
  'quot',
  'orang',
  'quot',
  'ware',
  'orang',
  'cloth',
  'app',
  'adiquit',
  'would',
  'recsmend',
  'want',
  'talk',
  'ghost'],
 ['love',
  'play',
  'backgammonthi',
  'game',
  'offer',
  'varieti',
  'difficulti',
  'make',
  'perfect',
  'beginn',
  'season',
  'player'],
```

***The case is that I would like to save in a list, the values that appear at least 1% in this array.***

The closest approximation I have found is the following but it does not return what I need. Any ideas?

```
import numpy_indexed as npi

idx = [np.ones(len(a))*i for i, a in enumerate(tokens_list_train)]
(rows, cols), table = npi.count_table(np.concatenate(idx), np.concatenate(tokens_list_train))
table = table / table.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)
print(table * 100)`
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"values that appear at least 1% in this array"_?

Comment: Hi! @PranavHosangadi I mean that they appear in general, it can be in another array as long as it is inside "data".

Comment: So you need to count all occurences of each word and then use the rule of three to find the percentage, right?

Comment: Hi! @Cpt.Hook Yes, it could be one of the approximations...the important thing is to obtain those that represent at least 1%.

Comment: How will you know until you computed the answer? You need to compute the answer for all and then return the ones above your limit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's see, we can remove the nesting using `itertool.chain.from_iterable`, but we also need the total length, which we can compute by making another generator to avoid looping twice, and we need to count the repetitions, which is done by a counter.

```py
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

total_length = 0
def sum_sublist_length(some_list):  # to sum the lengths of the sub-lists
    global total_length
    for value in some_list:
        total_length += len(value)
        yield value
        
counts = Counter(chain.from_iterable(sum_sublist_length(my_list)))
items = [item for item in counts if counts[item]/total_length >= 0.01]
print(items)
```

```
['amazon', 'phone', 'serious', 'mind', 'blown', 'enjoy', 'use', 'applic', 'full', 'websit', 'allow', 'quick', 'track', 'packag', 'descript', 'say', 'would', 'app', 'real', 'thing', 'show', 'ghost', 'said', 'quot', 'orang', 'ware', 'cloth', 'adiquit', 'recsmend', 'want', 'talk', 'love', 'play', 'backgammonthi', 'game', 'offer', 'varieti', 'difficulti', 'make', 'perfect', 'beginn', 'season', 'player']
```

Comment: Hi! @AhmedAEK I understand that to adapt your code to my data I only have to change "my_list" for the name of my array, right?

Comment: @NosequinposarTampoc yes.

Comment: Mostly I say this because I see far fewer than you in the final list.

Comment: @NosequinposarTampoc the list you posted in the question contains only a subset of the elements, as its length increases you will start seeing less elements.

Comment: it works perfectly but how can I modify the code to choose the common tokens in at least 1% of the comments and then count the number of times each of those tokens appears in each review and generate, for each review, a vector of numeric variables in which each position refers to each of those relevant or common tokens and indicates how many times that token appears in the comment in question.

Comment: @NosequinposarTampoc this seems like NLP, so you should search for NLP in python, you'll find plenty of frameworks with similar capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to generate a list of elements that appear 1% or more of the time, using `pandas.DataFrame`:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


# == Define `flatten` function to combine objects with multi-level nesting =======
def flatten(iterable, base_type=None, levels=None):
    """Flatten an iterable with multiple levels of nesting.

        >>> iterable = [(1, 2), ([3, 4], [[5], [6]])]
        >>> list(flatten(iterable))
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

    Binary and text strings are not considered iterable and
    will not be collapsed.

    To avoid collapsing other types, specify *base_type*:

        >>> iterable = ['ab', ('cd', 'ef'), ['gh', 'ij']]
        >>> list(flatten(iterable, base_type=tuple))
        ['ab', ('cd', 'ef'), 'gh', 'ij']

    Specify *levels* to stop flattening after a certain level:

    >>> iterable = [('a', ['b']), ('c', ['d'])]
    >>> list(flatten(iterable))  # Fully flattened
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    >>> list(flatten(iterable, levels=1))  # Only one level flattened
    ['a', ['b'], 'c', ['d']]

    """
    def walk(node, level):
        if (
            ((levels is not None) and (level > levels))
            or isinstance(node, (str, bytes))
            or ((base_type is not None) and isinstance(node, base_type))
        ):
            yield node
            return
        try:
            tree = iter(node)
        except TypeError:
            yield node
            return
        else:
            for child in tree:
                yield from walk(child, level + 1)
    yield from walk(iterable, 0)


# == Problem Solution ==========================================================
# 1. Flatten the array into a single level list of elements, then convert it
#    to a `pandas.Series`.
series_array = pd.Series(list(flatten(array)))

# 2. Get the total number of elements in flattened list
element_count = len(series_array)

# 3. Use method `pandas.Series.value_counts() to count the number of times each
#    elements appears, then divide each element count by the
#    total number of elements in flattened list (`element_count`)
elements = (
    (series_array.value_counts()/element_count)
    # 4. Use `pandas.Series.loc` to select only values that appear more than
    #    1% of the time.
    # .loc[lambda xdf: xdf['rate_count'] >= 0.01, :]
    .loc[lambda value: value >= 0.01]
    # 5. Select the elements, and convert results to a list
    .index.to_list()
)
print(elements)
['would', 'serious', 'blown', 'quot', 'orang', 'app', 'ghost', 'say', 'use', 'adiquit', 'enjoy', 'said', 'cloth', 'thing', 'applic', 'talk', 'player', 'track', 'recsmend', 'beginn', 'packag', 'allow', 'perfect', 'want', 'real', 'love', 'full', 'show', 'play', 'make', 'backgammonthi', 'mind', 'amazon', 'game', 'difficulti', 'offer', 'descript', 'websit', 'quick', 'season', 'phone', 'variety', 'ware']
```